# APEX: URL not valid when queried

Tags: apex

I'm getting the url from a custom setting, but for some reason I cannot understand, the url is not read properly. I've a sample code to demonstrate the issue. When is use the 'expected' variable in code it works, but when using 'actual' variable, even though it returns the same url, it fails. I've shown the error below as well. Any thoughts/ideas? Field type of endpointURL__c is URL(255)

```
Url expected = new Url('https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myqueue');       

Custom_Setting__c credential = [Select endpointURL__c from Custom_Setting__c limit 1];
Url actual = new Url(credential.endpointURL__c);

System.assertEquals(expected, actual);
```

> System.AssertException: Assertion Failed:

Expected: Url:[delegate=https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myqueue],

Actual:   Url:[delegate=https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/myqueue]

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I think there was a bad special character in the field when i created the custom setting. Resetting the field value with text resolved my issue.